# Как узнать **ServiceName** службы по ее исполняемому файлу

Tags: c#

Как узнать **ServiceName** службы по ее исполняемому файлу? Т.е. знаю только полный путь файла службы (например: "c:\Temp\WindowsService.exe"). Не знаю установлена служба или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Management;

private string getServiceName(string servicePath)
{
    string result = null;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
    ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
    {
        string name = obj["Name"] as string;
        string pathName = obj["PathName"] as string;
        if (pathName != null && pathName.Contains(servicePath))
        {
            result = name;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Посмотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828588/finding-the-actual-executable-and-path-associated-to-a-windows-service-using-c-s)

Comment: спасибо, работает, но только для установленной службы. а если служба еще не установлена, как то можно узнать ее ServiceName?

Comment: Имя службе дается при установлении, так что до установки узнать, под каким именем будет установлена, думаю что невозможно.